# How to auto redirect if access home '/' route on Laravel

Tags: laravel

i Using laravel 5.8 and have users with role . like role 1 , 2 ,3 . 1 : isAdmin , 2 : isEmployee , 3 : isManager .

i create midleware on this role like this :

```
    class AdminMiddleware
{

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {


        $user = $request->user();

        if($user){
            if($user->isAdmin())
            {
                return $next($request);
            }
        }


        return abort('401');
    }
}
```

and i add its on model users :

```
public function isAdmin()
{
    if($this->roles_id == 2)
    return true;

    return false;
}
```

and i add this to LoginController :

```
 protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    if ( $user->isAdmin() ) {// do your margic here
        return redirect()->route('admin_dashboard');
    }
    elseif ($user->isEmployee()) {
        return redirect()->route('pns_profile');
    }
    else{
        return redirect()->route('profile');
    }

}
```

and its stil work to multiauthentication . but i have problem .
if i close the browser . and i open again this project .its will redirect to home or '/' . like 
localhost/project/ . its will going to page home .

**i want to if i close browser ,and i open again , this session is active on adminMiddleware ,its will redirect to admin_dashoard ( localhost/project/admin_dashboard) . how i can do this ?**

Comment: What does your routes file look like?

Comment: you want to see my route redirect to home ? or what

Comment: I want to see your whole routes file, including how you’re attaching the middleware to the route.

Comment: yess i attcahing midleware on my route . and its run normally with midleware . but , its always redirect to home

Comment: Can we see how it’s used? How it’s organised?